# How to open multiple folders and compare the files in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a `parent_folder_1` and many sub folders inside that. I also have `parent_folder_2` and many sub folders inside that.

Sub folders contains .d files.

I have to get the number of `parent_folders` that the user wants to compare.

For example:

> "How many parent_folders do you want to compare?"

If the user inputs 4, then the script should ask for paths of all the four `parent_folders`.

And, in one parent folder, inside one sub_folder, there is another folder called `d folder`  which contains .d files.

I have to compare each .d file in all the four parent folders and have to put the results in an Excel spreadsheet as to which .d files are present in which parent folders.

If xxx.d sf present in `parent folder1` and `parent folder3`, then the output should be:

```
xxx.d  parent folder1 #this space is for parent folder2 if present# parentfolder3
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the idea:

- Use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) to traverse directories, sub-directories and files.
- In `wanted()`, check for:

  -f $File::Find::name && $File::Find::name =~ /^.+\.d$/
- If the above condition evaluates to false, return; else, compare the files and populate the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

U can try using

```
#opening the directory
opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;
#reading the directory 
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
print $file;}
#thus the giving the accessing the file in the way u would like to.
```